# How to take into account a line break with Beautifsoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am trying to understand how to do a line break when I want to have the value `name` on line 2:

```
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="sommetoken=1" />
    line 2 ->  <input type="hidden" name="**sommetoken2**" value="1" />   
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you are asking about getting the next `input` element knowing where the first one is.

In this case, you can use [`find_next_sibling()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-next-siblings-and-find-next-sibling):

```
first_input = soup.find("input", {"name": "return"})
second_input = first_input.find_next_sibling("input")

print(second_input.get("name"))
```